# How to count executed queries during selenium test?

Tags: django, django-testing

I have tried this below mentioned code, but it didn't work for me.

```
class SeleniumTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.driver = PhantomJS()

    @override_settings(DEBUG=True) 
    def test_queries(self)
        with self.assertNumQueries(10):
            self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + "/page-with-10-queries")
```

Output:

```
query['sql'] for query in self.captured_queries

AssertionError: 0 != 10 : 0 queries executed, 10 expected

Captured queries were:
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the queries generated by a view, I use the following code:

```
def test_queries(self):
    with self.assertNumQueries(3):
        found = self.client.get(reverse('<url name>'))
        print(found)  # This is the line that initiates the Lazy query
```

The following is a not tested suggestion but if you insist on using selenium you may try:

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True) 
def test_queries(self)
    with self.assertNumQueries(10):
        found = self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + "/page-with-10-queries")
        print(found)  # Just an idea
```